# React Component does not change output

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom, apollo-client, react-apollo

I'm trying to implement a react application with a three-layered architecture. But somehow I have problems when parents pass different inputs to their children, leading to not updating the dom.

My example looks as the following:

There is a component which is responsible for any api calls which looks like this:

```
export const ApiCall = (props) => {
  const { loading, error, data } = useQuery(ExampleQuery, {
    variables: { where: { "id": props.id } },
  });

  if (loading) return "Loading...";
  if (error) return "Error: Something went wrong";

  return (
    <div key={props.id}>
      <ExampleContainer data={data}/>
    </div>
  )

};
```

The container class gets the data and shall display different stuff in relation to the data:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

export class ExampleContainer extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            state: "",
        };
    }

    componentDidMount(){
        if(this.props.data.example.length === 0){
            this.onChangeState("DEFAULT");
          } else {
            this.onChangeState("SHOW");
          }
    }

    onChangeState = (state) => 
      this.setState({state:state});

    render() {
        const state = this.state.state;
        console.log(state);
        switch (state) {
            case "DEFAULT":
                return (
                    <div key={"DEFAULT"}>
                        <label>DEFAULT</label>
                    </div>
                )
            case "SHOW":
                console.log("it gets here but does not update");
                return (
                    <div key={"SHOW"}>
                        <label>Show something</label>
                    </div>
                )
            default:
                return null;
        }
    }
}
```

At first the input data is empty which makes the Container switch to state "DEFAULT". Then is displays DEFAULT as output. But when I now fire the query and some other data is passed, the state switches to "SHOW" but the output is still DEFAULT instead of SHOW. It even fires the console.log("it gets here but does not update") but the output is still not changed.

Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

PS: When I pass the onChangeState method to the View component which atm is not important for that problem, the state change works perfectly fine.

Comment: One thing is the `apiCall` should be `ApiCall` as this is a component, it should have a capital letter. Another thing is that you're not closing your "show" `</div>`

Comment: Oh i messed this up. In the application its with capital letter and the show div is closed

Comment: The rest looks ok to me, might help if you can create a runnable example of your issue (you can [embed one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/338537/how-do-i-create-a-react-stack-snippet-with-jsx-support) into your question or use something like [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/))

Answer (score -1):

I found the error while doing the example, my implementation actually works. I just messed up something else.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).